# memcpy for copying a fixed length buffer into a structure

Tags: c

I have this sample code:

```
struct
{
    char a[2];
    char b[2];
} buff;

char buffer1[5] = "ABCD";
```

To copy the `buffer1` to structure members, I am doing like this:

```
char c[3],d[3];
memcpy(&buff,buffer1,4);
sprintf(c,"%2.2s",buff.a);
sprintf(d,"%2.2s",buff.b);
printf("c=%s,d=%s",c,d);
```

When I print the variables c and d, I am getting the values in c and d variable properly as: `c="AB"` and `c="CD"`.

Well my question is, even though I am getting the output properly, will `memcpy` affect anything related to null character termination or have other unexpected memory-related consequences?

Comment: `When I print`....how? as `char` or as `string`?

Comment: Your struct buff has no null termination, unless you explicitly do this yourself.

Comment: Sourav, I edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: Didn't the edit reflect?. I approved the edit suggested by someone else. On top of that, I edited the question. May be that other person has to approve my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are two issues here:

1) As mentioned in comments you *likely* forget to include space for the ending `'\0'` (i.e. `NUL` in ASCII) terminator character. The `%s` format specifier for `printf` function expects that character string is in valid form. However nothing stops you from printing as sequence of characters, like here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
    char a[2];
    char b[2];
} buff;

char buffer1[5] = "ABCD";

int main(void)
{
    memcpy(&buff, buffer1, 4);

    printf("First member: %c%c\n", buff.a[0], buff.a[1]);
    printf("Second member: %c%c\n", buff.b[0], buff.b[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

2) A more serious issue is that compiler may include arbitrary *padding* between struct members (as well as after last member), so `memcpy` may not work as expected. Instead of copying like that (as it may put bytes from array into a unused "wholes"). I would suggest individual copies of each member or maybe using `offsetof()` macro.

From N1570 `6.7.2.1/15` *Structure and union specifiers*:

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

and `6.7.2.1/17`:

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

Hence, you should split your `memcpy` into two calls, for instance:

```
memcpy(&buff.a, buffer1, 2); /* or replace 2 with sizeof buff.a */
memcpy(&buff.b, buffer1+2, 2);
```

Comment: That makes my answer look so poor. +1 to this answer and +1 to your top answer too, since I can't give a +2. :)

Answer (score 1):

`buffer1` is null terminated. However, the data members of `buff` are not, since you don't append a null terminator on them. Moreover, you don't have space for the null terminator!

So, no it won't affect it, since it's not there. You will get unexpected results when you try to use the functions of `stdio.h`, which expect a null terminated string.

---

Also, you might want to check my example [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/loopstructs-c/), about looping in a struct, that it's somehow relevant. I would suggest you to copy to one data member at a time and *not* in one go.

Answer (score 1):

That might not work as expected. There might be padding bytes between the fields in a structure. These are inserted between fields to have the next field start at a certain address-offset. This is mostly the word-size of the CPU or the bus-size, or a multiple thereof for cache-alignment.

This can be true even for `char []`, as that would allow to efficiently moves/copy such arrays using word-transfers.

For other types, padding is very likely and additionally you have to care about endianess.

Remember also that `memcpy` & friends exactly do what their names imply: they operate on a block of memory. The do not care about strings, they do not have an idea about "strings". Inserting any NUL-bytes would render them useless, so they don't.

Note that this approach is similar to casting incompatible pointer types. There are few places you are safe, but most times this is the road to hell (aka *undefined behaviour*).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct
{
        char a[2];
        char b[2];
}buff;

int main ( void )
{

        char buffer1[4] = "ABCD";

        memcpy ( &buff , buffer1 , 4 );

        printf ( "\n%s\n ", buff.a );
        printf ( "\n%s\n ", buff.b );

        return ( 0 );
}

o/p-->
 rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc 16.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 

ABCD

CD
 rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$

 #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct
{
        char a[3];
        char b[3];
}buff;

int main ( void )
{
        char buffer1[4] = "ABCD";

        memcpy ( &buff.a , &buffer1[0], 2 );
        buff.a[2]='\0';
        memcpy ( &buff.b , &buffer1[2], 2 );
        buff.b[2]='\0';

        printf ( "\n%s\n ", buff.a );
        printf ( "\n%s\n ", buff.b );

        return ( 0 );
}

o/p--->
 rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc 15.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 

AB

CD
 rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$
```

Comment: What is this supposed to tell me?

Comment: if it is not null terminated you can get an unexpected o/p .... so better to add null termination at the end

Comment: You should explain your answer, so people can grasp your idea.

Comment: i have given the o/p that itself is a good explanation right?

Comment: My bad .. .i should add comments .. thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: You wrote my program completely ;). I need expaination about any issues in this code.

Comment: see in the first prog  if you use %s which expect NULL at the end since you have not added NULL you will get unexpected o/p ... in the 2nd prog we have added NULL at the end ... and o/p is as expected ...